# Removing text using grep

Tags: bash

Trying to remove a line that contains a particular pattern in a text file.  I have the following code which does not work

```
grep -v "$varName" config.txt
```

Can anyone tell me how I can make it work properly, I want to make it work using `grep` and not `sed`.

Comment: "which does not work" doesn't help us much. Please post specific error messages or specific ways in which the result differs from what was expected. Are you using the backticks as part of your command? If so, that's where your problem is.

Comment: When you run this I'm sure it's just outputting all the lines of the file minus any that contain $varName.  You'd then have to direct this output to some other file and then `mv` that file back to the original filename.

Answer (score 6):

you can use sed, with in place -i

```
sed -i '/pattern/d' file
```

Answer (score 3):

grep doesn't modify files.  The best you can do if you insist on using grep and not sed is

```
grep -v "$varName" config.txt > $$ && mv $$ config.txt
```

Note that I'm using `$$` as the temporary file name because it's the pid of your bash script, and therefore probably not a file name going to be used by some other bash script.  I'd encourage using `$$` in temp file names in bash, especially ones that might be run multiple times simultaneously.

Comment: Better still, use the `mktemp` utility.

Answer (score 0):

try using -Ev

```
grep -Ev 'item0|item1|item2|item3'
```

That will delete lines containing item[0-3]. let me know if this helps

Comment: grep doesn't delete anything. It either prints lines that matche or lines that doesn't match. You'll need to redirect output in order to save what is printed.

Comment: To clarify, the flags being used above will tell grep `-E` use an extended expression (correct in this case) and `-v` which turns grep into an "everything but...this stuff".  This method could be used here, but not as the OP wanted.  You would need to use this command and then redirect the output back into a file.  However you can't grep directly into the same file, so you'd have to grep > some other file and then copy the contents back.  `sed` is a better suggestion.